# _ <: Any? false

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm working on a scala macro, where I need to pass a Scala enumeration value as a type to an existing code.

I used a trick with `ConstantType`, where an arbitrary value (?) can be expressed as a unique type:

```
val c: blackbox.Context
val s: MethodSymbol = ???

c.internal.constantType(Constant(s)) // this gives me a UniqueConstantType instance
```

The problem appears, where I do not expect it. My macro fails to compile with an error:

```
type arguments [...] do not conform to class CoproductInstance's type parameter bounds [...]
...
[info] <notype>(SkyBlue) <: Any?
[info] false
...
```

where `<notype>` seems to be a (quite weird) String representation of the newly constructed type, and `SkyBlue` is my symbol that represents the enumeration value.

How is it possible, that something is not a subtype of `Any`?

Or is the message a red herring?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have reproducible example (without `???`)? `<notype>` is a special type, which is not a subtype of `Any`. You can check that `NoType <:< typeOf[Any]` is false.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I didn't know about the `NoType`. Will update the post with the specific example shortly

Comment: Scala 3 will be released this month and it has a completely different and much better macro system. I would thus highly recommend against messing around with Scala 2 macros – they're pure technical debt at this point.